# Finding ($2012$th term of the sequence) $\pmod {2012}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence given by formula:
>
> $a_1=1\\a_2=2012\\a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_{n}$
>
> find the value: $a_{2012}\pmod{2012}$

So, in fact, we have to find the value of $Fib_{2011}\pmod{2012}$ ($2011$-th term of Fibonacci sequence mod 2012) and I think it's the better way to think about it.

But don't know how to do that. I would be very grateful for help, because the problem intrigued me a lot.

Comment: $a_2=2012$ ? Are you sure?

Comment: that's the problem, sequence $a_n$ is given.. $a_n\neq Fib_n$, we have to find $a_{2012}\mod{2012}$ but it comes down to count $Fib_{2011}\mod{2012}$, because $a_1\mod{2012}=1, a_2\mod{2012}=0, a_3\mod{2012}=1$, and in general: $a_n\mod{2012}=Fib_{n-1}\mod{2012}$ .. if I'm not wrong of course..

Comment: check this: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40816/fibonacci-series-mod-a-number

Comment: nice, and very easy, thanks ;-) so the closed form formula isn't rather possible?

Comment: But $a_{2012}=F_{2010}\pmod{2012}$, not $F_{2011}\pmod{2012}$.

Comment: @Didier, you're right, thank you for pointing it out..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved using the Chinese remainder theorem. It is easy to check that modulo 4 the Fibonacci sequence is cyclic with a period 6. As $2010\equiv0\pmod6$ this means that
$$
F_{2010}=F_0=0\pmod4.
$$
Modulo the prime factor $503\mid2012$ we can use the usual Binet's formula
$$
F_n=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\tau^n-(-1)^n\tau^{-n}\right),
$$
where $\tau=(1+\sqrt5)/2$ is the golden ratio,
but we need to reinterpret $\sqrt5$. By quadratic reciprocity we have
$$
\left(\frac5{503}\right)=\left(\frac{503}5\right)=\left(\frac35\right)=-1,
$$
so $5$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $503$. This means that we need to move the arithmetic to the finite field $K=F_{503^2}=F_{503}[\tau]$, with $\tau^2=\tau+1$.
In $K$ the mapping $F:x\mapsto x^{503}$ is the unique non-trivial field automorphism, so it satisfies
$F(\tau)=-\tau^{-1}$, as $\tau$ and $-\tau^{-1}$ share the same minimal polynomial
over the prime field. So in the field $K$ we have $\tau^{503}=-\tau^{-1}$
and thus also $\tau^{504}=-1$ and $\tau^{1008}=1$. Therefore $\tau^{2010}=\tau^{2\cdot1008-6}=\tau^{-6}$
and similarly $\tau^{-2010}=\tau^6$.
This means that modulo 503 we have
$$
F_{2010}\equiv\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\tau^{-6}-\tau^6\right)=-F_{6}=-8.
$$
So we know that $F_{2010}\equiv -8\pmod{503}.$ Together with our earlier calculation modulo 4 (and the Chinese remainder theorem) we can conclude that
$$
F_{2010}\equiv -8\pmod{2012}.
$$
Note: it seems to me that we also proved that the Fibonacci sequence has period $1008$ modulo $503$ (but this may not be the smallest period). See the wikipage on [Pisano periods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) for more information.

Comment: But $a_{2012}=F_{2010}\pmod{2012}$, not $F_{2011}\pmod{2012}$.

Comment: Arrrggh! Thanks, @Didier!

Comment: Sorry... but your method goes through, doesn't it?

Comment: Sure, editing....

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for misleading!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, as always thank you for beautiful answer. I also have tried to solve it by Chinese reminder theorem ($F_n \mod{4}$ was easy). Unfortunately $F_n \mod{503}$ isn't that easy and actually my state of knowledge does not allow me to completely understand this solution.. But some day, when I will be smarter, I will come here and read your post once again, thank you!

Comment: @xan, very basic facts about finite fields and field extensions were used. I don't see a way to do without those facts, i.e. not within a reasonable space. Trust me, they are not deep at all, and should be covered in a first course dealing with field extensions. In other words, you don't need to become smarter to understand the details here. You will need a bit more exposure to algebraic structures though :-)