# Least period of the Fibonacci sequence in a field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields, fibonacci-numbers

Actually, I'm solving some exercises from the book "Finite Field" by Rudolf Lidl et al.

There is an exercise for which the idea is missing to solve it:

Let $r$ be the least period of the Fibonacci sequence in the finite field $F_q$  i.e.  the sequence with $s_0= 0, s_1= 1$, and $s_{n+2}=s_{n+1}+s_n$, for $n \geq 0$.  Let $p$ be the characteristic of $F_q$. Prove that $r=20$ if $p = 5$, that $r$ divides $p-1$ if $p =$ +/- 1 mod 5 and that $r$ divides $p^2-1$ in all other cases.

Could anyone help me with a good idea / a good proposition?

Comment: I think you need the explicit formula for $f_n$ in term of $\phi^n=(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n$ for $p \ne 2,5$ it is an element of $\Bbb{F}_{p}$ or $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ depending on $(\frac{5}{p})=(\frac{p}{5})$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period

Comment: [This old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/150062/11619) describes the basic idea. You need the law of quadratic reciprocity to decide whether the golden ratio is an element of $\Bbb{F}_p$ or $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$. Then you need to deduce that in the latter case, the conjugate of the golden ratio must be the Frobenius conjugate. After that you are basically done.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite Fibonacci technique is
the [matrix formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form), which is well worth knowing and [easily proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61997/proof-of-this-result-related-to-fibonacci-numbers):
$$
A^n=
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n=
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$

The first part of the question follows easily. Indeed,
$A^2=A+I$ and so $A^5=5A+3I \equiv 3I \bmod 5$.
Therefore, $A^{20} \equiv 3^{4} I \equiv I \bmod 5$.
Since $A^4 = 3A + 2I \not\equiv I \bmod 5$, the period mod $5$ is $20$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I got the second part of the question, but the third one (in all other cases) is difficult...could you show me a hint for this?